# defining array in pug.js

Tags: arrays, pug

I can't understand the difference. What is wrong here? Whenever I write it like this in pug—

```
-const users =[
    {
      "key":"Property",
      "key":"Property",
    }];
```

—it throws an error. And when I write it like this—

```
-
  const users =[
     {
       "key":"Property",
       "key":"Property",
     }];
```

—it does not throw errors and gives the right result.

Please help me if you know the difference.

Comment: Both versions look correct to me. What error are you getting with the first version? What version of Pug are you using?

Comment: @mtsknn I am getting this error: Error: F:\practice\node js\express generator\myapp\views\users.pug:2:5
    1| -const users = [
  > 2|     {
-----------^
    3|     'firstName': 'Aneeq',
    4|     'lastName': 'Akbar',
    5|     'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/nilsonjacques',

unexpected text "{
   "

Answer (score 0):

[Unbuffered code in Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) must either all be on one line, or it must all be indented beneath a hyphen (`-`), with the hyphen on a line by itself.

```
// this is ok
- let users = ['foo', 'bar']


// this is also ok
-
  let users = [
    'foo',
    'bar'
  ]


// this isn't ok
- let users = [
    'foo',
    'bar'
  ]
```

Placing content beside the hyphen signals to Pug that the code is all on one line, and it doesn't treat the next line as code, even if it's indented.